# Simple databases as an alternative to using sql?

Tags: database, alternate

Hi I've come to the point with my comparison site where I will need some kind of database, I've been messing about with it and honestly, it seems overly complicated for what I need, what do you think is the best alternative. I was thinking just a big CSV file would probably work (even if this isn't the best route for performance I could always change down the line if it ever becomes relevant)

I need to store probably like 5 links and 4 numbers for each "item"

any other makeshift database methods?

Comment: Just make a Postgres or MySQL database they’re not hard at all and will save you a head ache or twenty.

Comment: If you want to use a database, use a database.  If you want to use a CSV file, use a CSV file.  It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking of us.